# Short story from the 70s or 80s - A female protagonist turns into an animal to escape being attacked

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

When I was young, I had a collection of short SF/F stories. At the time, Conan the Barbarian was gaining popularity but I think this may have preceded the Arnold Schwarzenegger movie from 1982.

I can't remember any other stories than one wherein a woman is an assassin or bounty hunter, and she's off to capture a mark. The woman sword fights with one breast bared, and she raises her sword near the naked breast to distract any male opponents.

Now, I may be conflating two or more stories from the collection here, but I believe she has a device which enables her to transform herself into an alien animal. The planet she's going to has an infamously violent and strong animal so the safest way to avoid being killed by them is to become one of them. As she's pursuing her mark, she happens upon one of these animals and uses her device to transform herself into one of them.

At the end of the story...

> ...the animal charges forward and destroys her device so she's stuck being that animal, and learns that the mark is the animal she ran into, having used a similar device himself. He deliberately baited her to the surface so she would use the device and then he'd have her as a "mate."

Anyone know the story? the collection name? And if you can summarize the other stories in it, that'd be awesome too.